# Targeting different screen sizes for Android

Tags: android, screen

How should be the Android manifest.xml for separately targeting the following screen sizes in Google store: 
        800px*1280px, 
        600px*1024px, 
        360px*640px, 
        320px*530px

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are not screen sizes. They are screen resolutions. There is nothing that you do in the manifest for screen resolutions.

You may wish to read [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) on supporting different screen sizes and densities. This subject is also covered in any decent book on Android app development.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to distinguish 800px*1280px and higher resolution from the rest?

Comment: @CemilTatoglu: Device resolution is meaningless, given that Android 7.0+ (and the Android environment on Chrome OS) supports multiple windows.